# Why can't I take a screenshot on my second monitor on my Mac?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, multiple-monitors, screenshot

Whenever I attempt to take a screenshot on the second monitor, it fails silently. Is this possible, or do I have to move whatever I want to take a picture of onto the first monitor?

- Using Snow Leopard

Answer (score 8):

You can do this easily with the **grab** utility found under **Applications -> Utilities**.

There are 4 capture modes: Selection, Window, Screen, Timed Screen. If you select the Screen mode, grab will tell you to select the screen you wish to capture.

Comment: That isn't working for me either

Comment: What about **Command-Shift-4** then **Space**. It will allow you to select a window on any screen. Does that work?

Comment: I can select the window and it works on my main monitor, but not my secondary

Comment: What about `screencapture -i` from the Terminal? I've never seen this behavior before.

Comment: Doesn't work on the second monitor either :-(

Comment: I just had the same issue (a macbook pro and an additional 24" monitor) and was able to use the **Cmd+Shift+4** then **Space** to select which monitor I wanted my screenshot from. Once hitting that keystroke combo, the cursor turns into a camera icon, and creates a light blue overlay on whichever screen you want to select. You just click on that screen and that's the screen grab you get.

Comment: You could also just use **Cmd+Ctrl+Shift+4** and select the entire screen area with the crosshairs.

Answer (score 4):

Below are the key combinations for screen captures, copied from http://www.pointlessart.com/education/Screen-CaptureKeystrokes.htm

In my experience the most general purpose is cmd-shift-3, which makes multiple files on your desktop if you have multiple screens.

Press Cmd-Shift-3 to create a picture file on your hard drive, in the PICT graphics format, that depicts the entire screen image. A satisfying camera-shutter sound tells you that you were successful. (The file is called Picture 1. Each time you press Cmd-Shift-3, you get another file, called Picture 2, Picture 3, and so on.) You can open this file into SimpleText, Photoshop, AppleWorks, or another graphics program, in readiness for editing or printing.

Press Cmd-Shift-4 to turn your cursor into a tiny + symbol. Now drag diagonally across the screen to capture only a square chunk of it. When you release the mouse, you hear the camera-click sound, and a Picture 1 file appears on your hard drive.

Add Caps Lock to the Cmd-Shift-4 keystroke to turn your cursor into a bullseye symbol. Now you can capture only one window or dialog box - after you click inside it. This trick saves you the trouble of cropping out unnecessary background details in your graphics program

Add Control to either of those keystrokes if you want the resulting image to be copied onto your Clipboard, ready for pasting into (for example) Photoshop or AppleWorks, instead of creating a PICT file on your hard drive.

Comment: Cmd-Shift-3 is still only showing one monitor

Comment: Note that on Snow Leopard, names of screenshots will be formatted like: "Screen shot {date} at {time}" which is really nice because then you can easily tell when the screenshot was taken.

Comment: Those guidelines, while still somewhat accurate, date from the pre-Mac OS X days. Note that screenshots are now saved in the PNG format, with a different naming scheme (files still are saved to the Desktop, but the exact file name depends on the version of OS X). Also, you don't use Caps Lock to capture specific screen elements, you hit Space Bar after hitting Cmd-Shift-4.

Answer (score 2):

This stopped working when OSX added that feature where the Doc jumps from monitor to monitor. Whatever they did messes up the ability to take screen shots after you move your laptop between single/multi-monitor setups.

Answer (score 2):

**Use ⌘⇧5** (command-shift-5) =
You will see all the mentioned options in a little menu (screen/window/portion select, where to save, timer, etc and the same even with RECORD), works since OS 10.14.
Apple has simplified the process, a good move - without eliminating the older ones.
Taken from https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/370085/11120

Comment: This worked for me on MacOS Monterey. As other stated, I could capture the whole screen on my secondary monitor, it always defaulted to capturing the entire screen in my primary macbook built in display. With ⌘⇧5 I can select the whole screen button and click on my secondary monitor and it just work. With ⌘⇧4 it did not worked for me for the complete screen capture, everything else works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

**Cmd+Ctrl+Shift+4** will do what you need then you can move your mouse cursor to any open tab/window on any of your screens then by clicking the left mouse click it will take a shot

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers (and other comments) ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.